# Angular Material 2 .mat-ink-bar not showing in mat-tab-nav-bar

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

When I use the Angular Material 2 with `md-tab-group`, the `mat-ink-bar` shows up correctly and I can style it by using the .`mat-ink-bar` class.

But when I use `mat-tab-nav-bar` and router, the ink bar doesn't show. What could be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have found Solution 
You need to write code like below add **#rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive"**

`<a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/tab-1']"  #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive" routerLinkActive> Tab 1 </a> 
<a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/tab-2']"  #rla2="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla2.isActive" routerLinkActive> Tab 2 </a>
<a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/tab-3']"  #rla3="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla3.isActive" routerLinkActive> Tab 3 </a>`

Thanks